# Software to completely restrict Internet Access?

Tags: windows-xp, internet, restrictions

I need to completely restrict Internet browsing in one computer with Windows XP installed.

I have read many methods which imply editing the hosts file, using Internet Explorer filters, etc. The problem with these solutions is that they are not flawless unless you're running a limited account, which is not possible in my case.

Is there any software that restricts this kind of activity under, say, a password?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I'm running an admin account because the machine runs a POS (Point of Sale) software which cannot be run under a limited account.

Comment: If the user in question is running an admin account they could simply uninstall, reset or disable *anything* you put in place - that's the point of an admin account after all. You should either make them a limited user (is there a specific reason you cannot do this already?), or instead look at blocking them from *outside* of the machine - from your router for example.

Comment: The reason I need to run an administrator account is that we're running a POS (Point of Sale) software which can't run correctly under a limited account. We don't want the employees to lurk around the Internet and want to specifically use the connection for remote access.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should configure your router to restrict access for the machine.

An user with an admin account can reverse every change you made and disable any protection you install. That's what admin accounts are for. So any measure you take to limit internet access on the machine itself is useless.

The most fairly modern routers allow you to block internet access to certain machines. This feature may be called "parental control" (that's what this mechanism is usually used for) or something similar.

If your router doesn't support this, you may have to reconfigure your network (routing the machine in question through another machine with two network interfaces) or find another solution. IMHO a software solution can *always* be bypassed.

Comment: +1 For two possible solutions. The router option is what I would go for, but the option of routing the machine's network through another is a great alternative, then there are software options for the run-through machine that the admin on the original does not have access to.

Comment: I'll look into the router alternative, thank you very much.